# IntelliJ IDEA shows a colored rectangle when running via VNC (JetBrains Privacy Policy dialog)

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, redhat, vnc

When I remotely launched IDEA via VNC, an exception was displayed
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure a greater bit depth for your window manager using `vncserver -depth 24`. Here is a related issue in JetBrains issues tracker - [IDEA-235386](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235386).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the marked comment, if you have similar problem and you are using Remote Desktop Connection, you can go to `show Options` and then to the tab `Display` and in `colors` change to 24 bit (True Color).

BTW, more bizarre display problems in Remote Desktop Connection can be solved that way.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by

1. Open Windows remote desktop
2. Click on Show Options
3. Go to display Tab
4. Change color setting to True Color.